# Cassandra Compound primary key CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cql3

If I want to partition my primary key by time window would it be better (for storage and retrieval efficiency) to use a textual representation of the time or a truncated native timestamp ie

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
user_id TEXT,
log_day TEXT, -- store as 'yyyymmdd' string
log_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
data_item TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, log_day), log_timestamp));
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
user_id TEXT,
log_day TIMESTAMP, -- store as (timestamp-in-milli - (timestamp-in-mills mod 86400)
log_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
data_item TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, log_day), log_timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your column key "log_timestamp":
If you are working with multiple writing clients - which I suggest, since otherwise you probably won't get near the possible throughput in a distributed write-optimized data base like C* - you should consider using [TimeUUIDs](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/cql_data_types) instead of timestamps, as they are conflict-free (assuming MAC addresses are unique). Otherwise you would have to *guarantee* that no two inserts happen at the same time, otherwise you will lose this data. You can do column slice queries on TimeUUIDs and [other time based operations](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#timeuuidFun).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e. *1234567890*) over either of those formats - to point to an entire day, you'd just use the timestamp for 00:00.

However, I very much recommend reading [Advanced Time Series with Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra) on the DataStax dev blog. It covers some important things to consider in your model, with regards to bucketing/splitting.

Comment: Timestamp is just a long under the hood, so you might as well use that unless int resolution is enough.